# How to add Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-media-center, windows-8

On Windows 8 Pro, I'm trying to add Windows Media Center using the **Add features to Windows 8** dialog, but when I enter my product key I get the message `This key won't work. Check it and try again, or try a different key.`

[image: Add features to Windows 8 error]

I ditched my cable boxes for Cable cards, so I can't watch TV without Windows Media Center.

How can I install it? Do I need to buy a key for it?

Comment: I am going to guess you won't be able Media Center until the GA release of Windows 8 in Oct.  You also need to purchase the Media Center add-on, Windows 8 Pro DOES NOT INCLUDE IT, its just the only version eligible to purchase it.  Besides....The price of said add-on has not been released, which means you cannot purchase it, and Windows 8 TechNet licenses might not even be eligble to purchase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After patiently waiting for the official launch of Windows 8 for my key to work, I was disappointed to see it didn't.

Fortunately though, until January 31st, 2013, Microsoft is offering the **Windows 8 Media Center Pack** for [free](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs).

If you don't have Windows 8 Pro, or miss the offer deadline, you would have to buy a key by choosing **I want to buy a key online**. The same website has a deal for the **Windows 8 Pro Pack** which includes, the Windows 8 Media Center Pack.

Answer (score 2):

Media Center is avaiable for free until Jan 2013, but you have to go to the microsoft website to get a a new key to install it, i.e. **you can NOT use your Windows 8 installation key!!**

Go to the following Microsoft page, enter your email address and they will email a key to add Media Center.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs

Answer (score 0):

[The key is public and free](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-release-preview-install-windows-media-center-143291)

MBFBV-W3DP2-2MVKN-PJCQD-KKTF7

Also [look in the FAQ at Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/faq) under "Using Windows 8 Release Preview"

Not sure if this applies to RTM versions of W8.

EDIT: reports that this key does not work for RTM versions.

Comment: I'm hesitant to try this due to that caveat at the end: "I was told that I must reactivate Windows, and it asked for a new product key. I entered the product key noted above, which worked."

Comment: Its on the microsoft site also, this is for Release Preview, not sure what needs to be done if you are using RTM....http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/faq

Comment: This key will not work for the RTM build currently available to MSDN/Technet subscribers.

Comment: I hate to downvote an answer like this, but because the answer was directed towards the Release Preview version, this answer should simply be deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound OP never clearly stated which version it was, I added the tag later to clarify. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Moab - If you do then I aplogize. Looking at the original revision it shows it having the `Windows 8` tag. It shows that you actually changed it to the `Windows 8 RTM` tag. He also mentions `Windows 8 Pro` which he wouldn't have used if he was using the Release Preview imo.